# I work late and my 4yr old wont go to sleep

Tags: toddler, bedtime

I work late and usually don't get home till 2 or 3 a.m. and my 4yr old is wide awake. Gives trouble to go to bed early when I'm away working. I don't want my kid going to sleep at 2 or 3 in the morning.

Comment: Hi there - this is really common, and in fact we have various questions on exactly this topic. Please read them - some will be found in the Related sidebar to the right